# Is there an ASCII arrow that will fit seamlessly with the box-drawing characters?

Tags: windows-10, ascii, command-prompt, prompt, ascii-art

I'm getting creative with my prompt and on part of it I'm trying to do the following:

`└→`

Though it looks better than this, even in the console it has a small gap.

[image]

Does anyone know of an arrow character that would not do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work with most fonts:

> ```
> ►
> 9658
> U+25Ba
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:  (U+1FB6C). The following 3 characters could be used for arrowheads in different directions.

It's a flush left right pointing triangle. See the "LEFT TRIANGULAR ONE QUARTER BLOCK" in "Symbols for Legacy Computing":

| Base | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U+1FB0x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB1x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB2x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB3x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB4x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB5x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB6x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB7x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB8x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FB9x |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBAx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBBx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBCx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBDx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBEx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U+1FBFx |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The Wikipedia entry also has a link to the official Unicode charts:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_for_Legacy_Computing

Comment: This is what your answer looks like in Edge v104: https://imgur.com/HKYN1T3

Comment: But I see an image on the Wikipedia link.

Comment: I see missing glyph symbols on my iPad as well. Do you see anything in the first Wikipedia table? My iPad messes that up too. It works much better on my Ubuntu system where I have GNU free fonts (https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) and JuliaMono (https://juliamono.netlify.app/) installed. Decent Unicode support is clearly not a priority for the commercial OS and browser vendors! woff files are available for both these fonts - I’ll check the html for this page, but SO could serve them if they don’t already!

Answer (score 1):

People, we clearly have an obsession with ARROWS.  These are all the thin, solid, straight, right-facing arrows that were displayed on my computer's Character Map.  One or more of these might line up with the box drawing characters, ─ for example, depending on your font.  Now let me put one before each of these arrow characters and you can see which works for you:

─→ ─⇾ ─► ─▶ ─▸ ─➔ ─➙ ─➛ ─➝ ─➜ ─➞ ─➢ ─➣ ─➤ ─⟶ ─⭢ ─⮚ ─⮞ ─⯈ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font to Courier New "fixed" it, but I don't really like it as a console font.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can use the unicode set of the [*arrow symbols*](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/), for example:

- <kbd>→</kbd> - [Rightwards Arrow](https://unicode-table.com/en/2192/)
- <kbd>⇒</kbd> - [Rightwards Double Arrow](https://unicode-table.com/en/21D2/)
- <kbd>⇉</kbd> - [Rightwards Paired Arrows](https://unicode-table.com/en/21C9/)
- <kbd>⇶</kbd> - [Three Rightwards Arrows](https://unicode-table.com/en/21F6/)
- - [Rightwards Heavy Arrow](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F846/)
- <kbd>↳</kbd> - [Downwards Arrow with Tip Rightwards](https://unicode-table.com/en/21B3/)
- etc.

---

<sup>See also: [How do I change the distance between words?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651526/15402945)</sup>

Comment: I was looking for the last one in the answer, but it doesn't render in my terminal. Instead, it is a box with question mark in it.

Comment: It was a problem with the default WSL terminal. Using `Windows Terminal` application helped solve it.