# How do I change the distance between words?

Tags: java, string, kotlin, char, whitespace

How can I change the distance between words in a string in Android Studio using the methods? I need the distance to be about half the size of the standard space.

```java
val spanMsg = SpannableStringBuilder()
    msg?.forEachIndexed { i, char ->//replacing non-printable characters
                                    //with their code and highlighting
        if (char.isControlChar()) {//checking for non-printable characters
            spanMsg.appendWithSpan(" ", RelativeSizeSpan(BLOCKS_INDENT))
            for(x in toHex(Character.toString(char)
                                    .toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE))!!) {
                spanMsg.appendWithSpan(
                        x,
                        ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),
                        BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK)
                )
            }
```

```java
fun SpannableStringBuilder.appendWithSpan(text: CharSequence, vararg what: Any) {
this.append(text)
what.forEach {
    this.setSpan(
            it,
            this.length - text.length,
            this.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
}
```

as I understand it, after `BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK)`, you can add a parameter to change the distance between words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different kinds of *spaces* with different *widths*:

- <kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> - [Tag Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/E0020/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [Hair Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/200A/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [Thin Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/2009/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [*Regular Space*](https://unicode-table.com/en/0020/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [No-Break Space](http://No-Break%20Space)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [Punctuation Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/2008/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [Figure Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/2007/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [En Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/2002/)
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> - [Em Space](https://unicode-table.com/en/2003/)

---

<sup>See also: [Is there an ASCII arrow that will fit seamlessly with the box-drawing characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66819744/15402945)</sup>